# Teamcity runs out of memory when cloning a repository

Tags: git, out-of-memory, teamcity

I'm trying to create a teamcity setup for building a Visual studio Solution.

I've created a git VCS root that points to a repository in our network (a git@XXX:YYY.git address type).

Teamcity gives me an error when trying to clone the repository. In the build log I can see:

```
Failed to collect changes, error: Error collecting changes for VCS repository '"myrepo_git" {instance id=15, parent internal id=5, parent id=myRepoGit, description: "git@192.168.xxx.yyy:myrepo.git#refs/heads/develop"}'
'git fetch' command failed (repository dir: <TeamCity data dir>/system/caches/git/git-72C073A1.git).
stderr: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.pack.BinaryDelta.apply(BinaryDelta.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.pack.BinaryDelta.apply(BinaryDelta.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.resolveDeltas(PackParser.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.resolveDeltas(PackParser.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.resolveDeltas(PackParser.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.parse(PackParser.java:507)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectoryPackParser.parse(ObjectDirectoryPackParser.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.parse(PackParser.java:448)
    at...
```

I've tried to monitor the windows agent during cloning, and I've always a free memory, for both disk and RAM, so the problem is not the agent PC (I suppose).

What can I check in order to fix this problem?

Comment: Out of memory errors can occur when software cannot allocate a single *contiguous* block of memory.  You might have a gigabyte free, but if the largest contiguous free region is 100MiB and you're trying to allocate 200MiB, you'll get an out of memory error.  Do you have some very large objects in your git repo?

Comment: No, they are all text files and some small binary files, like icons. In the history there are some big file that are there cause of commit errors, like some .dll files, but they are less than 10MB in size.

Comment: Ever solved this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I've rewritten the git remote history by removing big binary files committed by error. After cleaning the history everything went well

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this recently. I got ours to work by going to the Administration page->Diagnostics->Internal Properties and using the following for the "internal properties:"

```
teamcity.git.fetch.max.memory=1300M
teamcity.git.fetch.process.max.memory=1300M
teamcity.git.fetch.timeout=7200enter code here
```

Hope that helps if you haven't got things working by now.